# Error al mostrar variable en messagebox

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy realizando un conversor de unidades y me gustaría que al apretar el botón mostrara el número que he escrito en la caja de texto en el `messagebox`, pero no funciona. El `messagebox` siempre se muestra sin contenido sin importar lo introducido en el `Entry`.

Este es mi código:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
from string import*
from tkinter import messagebox


def Conversor():
    global numero
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Conversor Km a Mi")
    root.geometry("280x70+100+50")
    tk.Label(text='Conversor',fg='black',font=10) .pack()
    KMDATA = tk.Entry()
    KMDATA.pack(fill=X)
    numero = KMDATA.get()
    tk.Button(root, text='Convertir',fg="black",font=12, bg="light 
    green", command=varconv) .pack(side = BOTTOM, fill=X)

    root.mainloop()

def varconv():
    messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", numero)


Conversor()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en la línea:

```
numero = KMDATA.get()
```

Esto hace que **en el momento que ejecutas la función** la variable `numero` pase a tener como valor el contenido del `Entry` (`""` en ese momento). Cuando ingresas texto en el `Entry` esta variable no cambia, luego el `MessageBox` muestra siempre una cadena vacía.

Existen muchas formas de solucionar esto manteniendo tu código dentro de la función, básicamente debes obtener el contenido del `Entry` en el mismo momento en el que el botón es pulsado y no al inicio del programa:

- Hacer que `KMDATA` (o una `tkinter.StringVar` asociada a el) sea  global y usar `get` dentro de la función que crea el `MessageBox`:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk
  from tkinter import messagebox

  def conversor():
      global numero
      root = tk.Tk()
      root.title("Conversor Km a Mi")
      root.geometry("280x70+100+50")
      tk.Label(root, text='Conversor', fg='black', font=10).pack()
      numero = tk.StringVar(root)
      tk.Entry(root, textvar=numero).pack(fill=tk.X)
      tk.Button(root, text='Convertir', fg="black", font=12,
                bg="light green", command=varconv).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
      root.mainloop()


  def varconv():
      messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", numero.get())

  conversor()
  ```
- Prescindir del uso de variables globales y pasar la referencia del `Entry` o del `StringVar` como argumento (vía `lambda` o `functools.parial`):

  ```
  import tkinter as tk
  from functools import partial
  from tkinter import messagebox

  def conversor():
      root = tk.Tk()
      root.title("Conversor Km a Mi")
      root.geometry("280x70+100+50")
      tk.Label(root, text='Conversor', fg='black', font=10).pack()
      numero = tk.StringVar(root)
      tk.Entry(root, textvar=numero).pack(fill=tk.X)
      tk.Button(root, text='Convertir', fg="black", font=12, bg="light green", 
                command=partial(varconv, numero)).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
      root.mainloop()


  def varconv(var):
      messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", var.get())


  conversor()
  ```
- Puedes definir `varconv` directamente  dentro de la función `conversor`:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk
  from tkinter import messagebox
  from functools import partial

  def conversor():

      def varconv():
          messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", numero.get())

      root = tk.Tk()
      root.title("Conversor Km a Mi")
      root.geometry("280x70+100+50")
      tk.Label(text='Conversor', fg='black', font=10).pack()
      numero = tk.StringVar(root)
      tk.Entry(root, textvar=numero).pack(fill=tk.X)
      tk.Button(root, text='Convertir', fg="black", font=12,
                bg="light green", command=varconv).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
      root.mainloop()



  conversor()
  ```

Existen muchas otras posibilidades como usar POO:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class Conversor(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Conversor, self).__init__()
        self.title("Conversor Km a Mi")
        self.geometry("280x70+100+50")

        self.numero = tk.StringVar(self)

        tk.Label(self, text='Conversor', fg='black', font=10).pack()
        tk.Entry(self, textvar=self.numero).pack(fill=tk.X)
        tk.Button(self, text='Convertir', fg="black", font=12, bg="light green",
                  command=self.var_conv).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

    def var_conv(self):
        try:
            ent = float(self.numero.get())
            res = "{} mi".format(ent * 0.62137)
        except:
            res = "El valor introducido no es numérico"

        messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conv = Conversor()
    conv.mainloop()
```